# How to stop Array adapter from loading an entire list of data in Android?

Tags: android

So, I am writing a hacky version of endless adapter but I want to check if it is possible to stop loading data after a particular position or count even if I've passed a huge list of data to it.

What I meant is this:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (position(count) < 25)
               {
                       load data into the layout.
        }
           return convertView;
}
```

Currently I am getting a null pointer exception if I try something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would likely need to specify the number of views to display in [getCount()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getCount%28%29) and increase this as you wish to display more views.  Something like this would probably work (Note: I haven't tested this)

```
private class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private int currentMax;
    private ArrayList<MyType> items;

    public MyAdapter(int max, ArrayList<MyType> items){
        currentMax = max;
        this.items = items;
    }

    public void showMore(int howMany){
        currentMax += howMany;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount(){
        return currentMax;
    }

    /* snip (getview etc.) */
}
```

And then to use and increase

```
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(25, items);
getListView().setAdapter(adapter);

/* you now want to show more */

// Increase limit
adapter.showMore(10);
// Let the adapter know something's chagned
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```